# hibernate composite key ignore setting field

Tags: java, hibernate, composite-primary-key

So, I am trying to create some record that has references to some dictionary  declared as **composite key**

```
class Contact {
...
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(insertable = false, updatable = false, name = "contact_type", referencedColumnName = "dict_id"),
    @JoinColumn(insertable = false, updatable = false, name = "party_own_id", referencedColumnName = "dict_own_id"),
})
private ContactType contactType;
```

In hibernate service, I am setting **contactType** and saving it into database as

```
contactObject.setContactType(typeRepository.findByCode(type))
contactRepoistory.create(contactObject)
```

Everything works fine except that the hibernate **ignores** contact_type and makes insert statement without setted contact_type, but why?

As a workaround I've made custom column and I'm setting it with relation field ...

```
@Column(name = "contact_type")
private String contactTypeColumn;


public void setContactType(ContactType contactType) {
    this.contactType = contactType;
    this.contactTypeColumn = contactType.getCode();
}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated?

Comment: What do you expect when you define insertable = false, updatable = false ? It will not insert nor update the relationship

Comment: I took it from some documentation. I cannot set other values cause i cannot run hibernate context then. Beyond contact_type there is contact_kind field which is similar like this one but reference to contact_kind column

Comment: Remove insertable = false, updatable = false,

Comment: repeated column in mapping for entity: Client column: party_own_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false"). Party own id is setted in primary key object of client entity :(